# Invert matched regex pattern

Tags: regex

I has having an hard time trying to find a title that explains what I want.
I have this string

> "LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=Gkgd6113jsFPOF5vLuBBZ8l_jpP3tfqF7jSeZRWERWtrB_8XBjIiU9nMG25ywucGu5fTwCSJowux91liImgrQv6RdOdcI-BSyAxo8Ux4cnWu9fobOgc8BNsQpPhww6oZ8Sm_eBTKtmGqrhUZGE7wTJt_cpAxB0tNdDIthoZN1tpH7ZuoLcs0s6171HVfnWlKDj2dmOIw5OKU_fDtX-3YURZMuXpFeDUgAab41VgOgp3n2Z2LAWzqzfCmJ3_GzdyeViBkWqz5Ouc0Cwc4WPYtsjjq8miRb86eQe_p_oHq58U.;Path=/;HTTPOnly"

And I can use regex to select the cookie:

> Gkgd6113jsFPOF5vLuBBZ8l_jpP3tfqF7jSeZRWERWtrB_8XBjIiU9nMG25ywucGu5fTwCSJowux91liImgrQv6RdOdcI-BSyAxo8Ux4cnWu9fobOgc8BNsQpPhww6oZ8Sm_eBTKtmGqrhUZGE7wTJt_cpAxB0tNdDIthoZN1tpH7ZuoLcs0s6171HVfnWlKDj2dmOIw5OKU_fDtX-3YURZMuXpFeDUgAab41VgOgp3n2Z2LAWzqzfCmJ3_GzdyeViBkWqz5Ouc0Cwc4WPYtsjjq8miRb86eQe_p_oHq58U.

But I want to select the inverse, meaning:

> "LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY= ;Path=/;HTTPOnly"

This is my regex:

> \w+-\w+-\w+.

I've google it but i cant seem to find any solution.

Comment: What environment (language? tool?) are you using regex from? Many would offer the possibility to replace the cookie value by the empty string, which would leave you with your desired result

Comment: You can always use your regex to replace the matched text with an empty string. What remains will be the inverse.

Comment: `"LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=|;Path=\/;.*?"` would probably work.

Comment: What do you know ahead of time? E.g. do you know that "LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=" will exist, do you know that other text will follow the cookie, do you know what that is? Because the more you know ahead of time, the easier it will be.

Comment: @anubhava I'm using this on Apache NiFi and I'm testing this on regex101.com

Comment: @Aarox I'm using Apache NiFi, I did a GET Request on a URL and got those Cookies has attributes. But I need to trim them in order to get ONLY the cookie.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, well that was a way easier approach. It works, thank you!

Comment: @404 The "LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=" will always exists. It's the HTTP response !

Comment: Nice! I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to get everything before the cookie and everything afterwards:

```
"LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=|;Path=\/;.*?"
```

https://regex101.com/r/l26ey3/1